# SqlDependency with SQL Server 2014

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sqldependency

We are migrating SQL Server from 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2014 on cluster VM ware.

We have a .Net application in which we have implemented `SqlDependency` to track database changes in a Windows application.

Will `SqlDependency` still work smoothly in SQL Server 2014?

I heard that it is not supported or deprecated?

Any other way to replace `SqlDependency` in SQL Server 2014?

Please suggest and share valuable inputs.

Comment: Where did you *hear* that?? Neither the [Breaking Changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143179.aspx) nor the [Behavioral Changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143359.aspx) documents published by Microsoft mention ***anything*** along those lines .....

Comment: ok, Also wanted to know that any other new thing or way to achieve SqlDependency and track update of db changes in our application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an open source realization of the SqlDependency class - [SqlDependencyEx](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/blob/master/ServiceBrokerListener/ServiceBrokerListener.Domain/SqlDependencyEx.cs). It uses a database trigger and native Service Broker notification to receive the events about the table changes. This is an usage example:

```cs
int changesReceived = 0;
using (SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(
          TEST_CONNECTION_STRING, TEST_DATABASE_NAME, TEST_TABLE_NAME)) 
{
    sqlDependency.TableChanged += (o, e) => changesReceived++;
    sqlDependency.Start();

    // Make table changes.
    MakeTableInsertDeleteChanges(changesCount);

    // Wait a little bit to receive all changes.
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

Assert.AreEqual(changesCount, changesReceived);
```

Hope this helps.